# Place to quickly find Amtrak fares for multiple days?

Tags: usa, trains, budget, amtrak

There are a lot of sites that can show you air fares over a range of dates, some of them up to a month.  But where can I find something vaguely like that for Amtrak?

I'd like to go what ever day is the cheapest in a time span of three weeks or more, and I would rather not go to Amtrak.com and do one day at a time twenty times.

Rome2Rio will tell me a nice low price, but it won't tell me what day it is on.

Answer (score 4):

[Amsnag](http://biketrain.net/amsnag/amSnag.php) is what you want.

Note that for most Amtrak routes, especially the long distance ones, the base fares are relatively static from one day to the next - they will go up over time though as the cheapest tickets sell out. However the cost of bedroom accommodation can be 50% or even 100% higher from one day to another.

On the commuter routes such as the NE corridor there will be variation on fares throughout the day (and between train types).